# DBLint Rule 31 means

Tags: mysql, sql

DBLint is used to check database status. There are 46 rules. At www.dblint.org there are some simple explainations of each rule, but the Rule 31 which is described as below:

*Defined Primary Key is not a Minimal Key*:
A primary key is a minimal superkey. If the defined primary key is not a minimal superkey, it means that it is possible to identify a row with fewer attributes. Using a superkey instead of a primary key is even less attractive when other tables need to reference it. Each of the referencing tables will need to hold more information than actual needed, resulting in using more space and less efficient indices.

which is not quite clearify for me. If someone could explain this, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is a super key if as subset of the columns in the primary key can also be used to uniquely identify a row.

**Example:**

Let's say you have a table containing all employees in a company. Each person gets an id but you also have a requirement that each person have a unique alias consistent of three letters for login name, email etc. This table could be:

```
create table employee
(
    empID int not null auto_increment,
    alias nvarchar(3) not null unique,
    forname nvarchar(256) not null,
    lastname nvarchar(256) not null,
    constraint employee_pk primary key (empID, alias)
)
```

In this table the primary key is the combination of the empID and the persons three letter alias, but both the empID and the alias is required to be unique hence the primary key is a super key. It would be enough to only use a subset of the columns, e.g., the empID as a primary key to uniquely identify a single row, hence that will be a minimal super key.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Is the **alias** a minimal super key in your example? Since it is unique in the table and not null, each **alias** could identify a row uniquely.

Comment: Yes, in this example it is, but only because of the `not null` as you say, because it is possible to have multiple null values in the `unique constraint`